# Proper way to create a table for a many-to-many relation

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I'm a newbie at this so please bear with me.

Suppose I have two tables, TABLE_A and TABLE_B.

TABLE_A has a primary key PK_A, whereas TABLE_B has a primary key PK_B.

There is a many-to-many relationship between TABLE_A and TABLE_B.

The SQL string I used to try to create the table to model this relationship is:

```
CREATE TABLE many_to_many (
    PK_A CHAR(10)
    ,PK_B CHAR(10)
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_A FOREIGN KEY PK_A REFERENCES TABLE_A(PK_A)
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_B FOREIGN KEY PK_B REFERENCES TABLE_B(PK_B)
    ,CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (
        PK_A
        ,PK_B
        )
    );
```

My question is: is this approach valid?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method several time, and it works fine as long as you are sure you want to have **at most one relation** between each element of table A and each element of table B.

Comment: Could you clarify further, please?

Comment: the third constraint you have written means that you can only have one row for each couple (PK_A, PK_B). I don't know what your use case is, but sometimes that's not what you want.